# Using Ruby, can you use more than one rescue in a begin loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, twitter, error-handling, rescue

Is it possible to add more than one rescue in a begin loop and/or a function and still have a next as well for each?

For example:

```
begin twitter_function

rescue Twitter::Error::RateLimit => error
  next
rescue Twitter::Error::Unauthorized => error
  next
end
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen gonna try it now, jus gotta make the errors happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, We can do next in `begin - rescue` loop. We can do this in following manner -

```
for i in 1..10
  begin
    do_something_that_might_raise_exceptions(i)
  raise ExpectedError1 => error1
    next # do_something_* again, with the next i
  raise ExpectedError2 => error2
    next # do_something_* again, with the next i
  end
end
```

Comment: can we put more than one rescue in the begin?

Comment: Yes, we can do more than one rescue in begin loop.